# Lazy Instantiation Disadvantages iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, lazy-loading

So it seems lazy instantiation is widely used and everybody know the advantages of lazy instantiation.

Which leads to the question: should we lazy instantiate every object?

Which I seriously doubt.

So the question is, what are the disadvantages of lazy instantiation?

Sample taken from (Apple Sample LocateMe):

```
- (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {
    if (dateFormatter == nil) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    }
    return dateFormatter;
}
```

This will give us the advantage of only initialising this object when it is needed.

By the way, the above sample taken from Apple, it seems like they only lazy instantiate "readonly" objects.

Comment: Lazy instantiation is only really relevant to Singletons or those behind a factory. For instance, those living for the duration of aservice or application that provide some service - such as resource handling. You often just want to create a new object instance when you need it.

Comment: I'm more talking about the lazy instantiation in obj-c where we do them on collections, arrays etc. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Ok but the above still applies. Or, do you mean arrays accessed through, say `NSArray *arr = [NSArray array]`?

Comment: lazy loading for objects like that is generally seen as good practice mainly to conserve memory. I generally avoid lazy loading if there is a performance hit when creating an object

Comment: Yeah you can instantiate an NSArray like that. But some make a lazy getter for it. Also for example for CLLocationManager or any other object. Doesn't have to be collections.

Comment: Ok... I'm struggling to understand the specifics of your question (aside from the general question of lazy init in Objective C - and my answer above). Can you provide a code sample and word your question around it please?

Comment: I edited it a bit. Btw I agree on that @wattson12

Comment: the other advantage is readability, moving initialisation out of a common method like viewDidLoad makes it less bloated, but conversely if the setup makes the code more readable (e.g. the creation of an object has an effect on other objects or app logic) i wouldn't lazy load it. but having said that, most of this comes down to personal preference (and if your project has them, coding standards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured I'll reword my response in the form of an answer (ad you've got too many comments now)...

In the example you've given, it's safe to use the same object instance multiple times as its internal state is unaffected. That is, it's providing a service and won't keep state between calls.

As a general rule, lazy instantiation is only really relevant to Singletons or those instances provided through a factory. For instance, like in your example, instances living for the duration of a "service" or application - such as resource handling. Usually though, you often just want to create a new object instance when you need it.

The advantages/ disadvantages of lazy initialization are:

- You need initialize an object only once and a single instance will suffice for all service calls. State won't be held between calls. The benefit here is that the object may be time-consuming to load and so you avoid start up cost or, in a singleton context, you avoid instantiating multiple expensive objects. This also applies to memory footprint - one instance, rather than many.
- There is a cost at run-time though if you do lazily ini an object as you've essentially delayed its construction. So, at run-time, when a user is waiting, you go and create an expensive object. Not ideal so you should avoid this - if it's a long-service object again.
- In the example you've given, there's also a question of responsibility for memory. The client code is clearly responsible for releasing this instance. If it's a long serving object, where do they do it? Well, you may have to watch the NSApp's delegate for applicationWillTerminate.
- If an instance maintains state that would be set between invocations of methods on an instance then this pattern can't work. The state of the instance may be inconsistent (may have been changed) between calls.

Note also that this is an instance method setting the value of an instance var if it's null... This means that, in this case, you will still have one instance per your enclosing class instance (class where this method is defined). In this context, your enclosing instance is responsible for clean up. Really, I think that this is for clarity of code, rather than memory management. Or perhaps the enclosing class is long-lived and it saves re-creating your formatter (perhaps it's more expensive to recreate than reset).

will edit if anything else comes to mind. Hope it helps.